# angular http.get

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, angular

Есть сервис в котором хранятся функции вида:

```
getData(){
   this.http.get('/***/my.json')
    .subscribe((response) => {
     return response;
    });
}
```

Все они получают json обьект по разным "url"... Но в каждом получаемом объекте есть параметр "isset: boolean".
Могу ли я перехватывать в одном месте ответы на все запросы, и проверять значение этой переменной для каждого из них прежде чем функция вернет return??

Comment: что делает `return` внутри `subscribe`? это бесполезная операция

Comment: Не суть. Чисто абстрактный пример...

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум можно сделать так (сделал пример прямо в компоненте, у Вас это будет в сервисе) -

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';

interface IResponse {
  isset: boolean;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-common';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  loader = (url:string) => this.http
    .get(url)
    .pipe(filter((response: IResponse) => response.isset ))

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loader('...url')
    .subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

Хотя я не понял что значит проверять, но предположил что нужен фильтр, но вы можете использовать абсолютно любой оператор. Но если вы все же будите использовать фильт, то помните, что в случаи когда значение closest будет false, то подписчик не сработает и есть возможность ,что и отписку вытоже сделать не сможете.

Comment: подписка всегда будет и отписка также

Comment: @overthesanity не понял? Вы о том случаи, когда отписываться в onDestroy?Так да, будет..

Comment: а как еще отписываться? ;))

Comment: @overthesanity я ступил:) просто частоиспользую rxjs вне angular и там в compete\error отписыватьсяиногда приходится, если в promise не конвертируется. Не лишняя информация, есть о чемподумать :) Да и кто знает, может автор в сервисе возьмет да и подпишится.

Comment: ну, запомните, что когда вы напишете `subscribe` - объект весом 80 байт (`Subscription`) всегда попадет в память) и если используется `filter` - то можно использовать `takeUntil`, но это в том случае если поток горячий и постоянно генерирует события. В случае с методами `HttpClient` - все методы возвращают потоки, которые сами по себе `autocomplete`, поэтому какой бы оператор не использовался - отписываться не нужно и утечки не будет

Comment: @overthesanity про HttpClient и autocomplete не знал, спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Есть стандартный подход через `HttpInterceptor`. Получится должно что то такое.

```
  @Injectable()
  export class IssetInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
    {
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        map(response => response.isset ? {...response, foo:boo} : response)
     );
    }
  }
```

Ну и фильтры на `request` тоже ни кто не отменял.